# How to get the Input <input> text element value to <li> element using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user click on the input check box the element value from inside the element copied to another place named with item list.

Now I want to add an input text field and want to get the value of this field to the same place named with item list.

```
<!--  Input text field -->
    <input class="item" type="text" style="cursor: pointer;" value=" " >


  <!--  Item List -->
  <div id="grocery-list">
  <h3>Item List</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="empty">Empty</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waqasadil/7HQDK/105/) for better understanding.

Thanks in advance.As I am new here and if I have made any mistake in this post. Please correct it

Comment: Please add information like what is happening now and what do you want to achieve

Comment: where are you calling your `addToList` function?

Comment: I am calling it on Add button

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HQDK/106/)

I changed the button to `input type = submit`, then I changed the select JQuery selector to `$(".first_select option:selected").text()`

Comment: you are sending me the URl without updating the fiddle .Please update it by clicking on update at fiddle dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your `addToList()` function to accept an array of strings to add.

Then, in the `submit` handler, I just build up that array of strings and then pass it to the function. Much cleaner.

```js
  $("button").button();

  function addToList(items) {
    var $list = $("#grocery-list ul");
    $list.empty();
    jQuery.each(items, function(i, text) {
      $list.append("<li>" + text + " <a class='delete_li'>&#10006;</a> </li>");
    });
  }

  $("body").on("click", ".delete_li", function() {
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
  });

  $("form").on("submit", function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    $("fieldset").effect("transfer", {
      to: "#grocery-list ul",
      complete: function() {
        var items = [];
        // add text box values first
        $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
          items.push($(this).val());
        });
        // then add checkbox label texts if checked
        $("input:checked").each(function() {
          items.push($(this).next().html());
        });
        // finally, add the selected option values
        $('select :selected').each(function() {
          items.push($(this).val());
        });
        addToList(items);
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
#grocery-list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#grocery-list ul li + li {
  margin-left: 3%;
}
#grocery-list li {
  display: inline;
}
fieldset {
  width: 300px;
}
input {
  padding: .5em;
}
#grocery-list {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
#grocery-list h3 {
  margin-top: .3em;
}
.ui-effects-transfer {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!--  Item List -->
<div id="grocery-list">
  <h3>Item List</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="empty">Empty</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend style="width :500px; margin-top:0px">Add Item</legend>
    <label for="item">Item Name:</label>
    <br>

    <!--  Input text field -->
    <input class="item" type="text" style="cursor: pointer;" value=" ">

    <label></label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select style="position:absolute;margin-left:65px;margin-top:-18px;cursor: pointer;" class="first_select">
      <option class="item" sty>mg</option>
      <option class="item" value="saab">ml</option>

    </select>
    <select style="position:absolute;margin-left:120px;margin-top:-18px; cursor: pointer;" class="second_select">
      <option>STAT(once immediately)</option>
      <option>OD(once in a day)</option>
      <option>BiD(twice in a day)</option>
      <option>TiD(thrice in a day)</option>
      <option>QiD(four times a day)</option>
    </select>

    <select style="position:absolute;margin-left:290px;margin-top:-18px;cursor: pointer;" class="third_select">
      <option>1 day</option>
      <option>2 days</option>
      <option>3 days</option>
    </select>

    <input class="item" type="checkbox" style="position:absolute;margin-left:360px;margin-top:-15px;cursor: pointer;">
    <label style="position:absolute;margin-left:375px;margin-top:-16px">Before Food</label>
    <input class="item" type="checkbox" style="position:absolute;cursor: pointer;margin-left:460px;margin-top:-15px">
    <label style="position:absolute;margin-left:475px;margin-top:-16px">After Food </label>

    <button class="button button3" style="position:absolute;margin-left:0px;margin-top:20px; width:100px; height:60px ">Add</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To append the value to your list you can add a attribute onclick to yout button. also use ids for your html elements. it makes your code more readable and you can use more input fields and buttons in one page.it would look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="inputvalue">
<ul id="itemlist">
</ul>
<button id="submit" onclick="append()"/>
<script>
    function append() {
        var input = $('#inputvalue').val();
        $('#itemlist').append('<li>' + input + '</li>');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this is what you are expecting. refer the working demo below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">



</style>


<body>

 <input class="item" type="text" style="cursor: pointer;" value=" " >


  <!--  Item List -->
  <div id="grocery-list">
  <h3>Item List</h3>
  <ul class="thelist">
    <li class="empty">Empty</li>
  </ul>
  </div>

<button>
<a class="button">
click
</a>
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".button").click(function(){
    var the_input_value = $(".item").val();
    $("ul.thelist li").hide();
    if (the_input_value == "") 
    {
        alert("Value cannot be null");
    }
    else
    {
        var create_li = $("<li>"+the_input_value+"</li>");
        $("ul.thelist").append(create_li);
        $(".item").val("");
    }
});


</script>




</body>


</html>
```

**or else if you want to show all items,which user enter do like below.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">



</style>


<body>

 <input class="item" type="text" style="cursor: pointer;" value=" " >


  <!--  Item List -->
  <div id="grocery-list">
  <h3>Item List</h3>
  <ul class="thelist">
    <li class="empty">Empty</li>
  </ul>
  </div>

<button>
<a class="button">
click
</a>
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".button").click(function(){
    var the_input_value = $(".item").val();
    $("ul.thelist li:first-child").hide();
    if (the_input_value == "") 
    {
        alert("Value cannot be null");
    }
    else
    {
        var create_li = $("<li>"+the_input_value+"</li>");
        $("ul.thelist").append(create_li);
        $(".item").val("");
    }
});


</script>




</body>


</html>
```